# How can I observe all network traffic to and from a certain domain in OSX?

Tags: networking, macos, wireless-networking, http, https

I'd like to observe requests from my machine to certain domains and optionally insert my own canned responses instead of the ones they provide.

eg: any `GET` request to `api.googlemaps.com` I intercept and return `{ test: "foo" }`

I'd like this to work for HTTP and HTTPS, though it'd be ok if I can't read the contents of the HTTPS messages, and just make up my own.

I'm not sure how to get started on this. Any ideas?

If it matters, I'm on OSX 10.11.4

Comment: I would start with [Charles Proxy](http://www.charlesproxy.com/) and see if that works for you.

Comment: @heavyd I would like something programmable, or at least scriptable. Does charles allow me to save responses as files to disk and restructure the shape of JSON?

Comment: I honestly haven't ever used it, as I don't have any OSX machines, but I do see it recommended often.   If you have access to a Windows machine, I know that [Fiddler](http://www.telerik.com/fiddler) will allow you to do everything you need, including scripting responses.

Answer (score 0):

For observation you can use Wireshark traffic analyzer. They have OSX version.

As for changing the answers from your machine - it's another story.
This is rather complicated. You should consider that any https conversation is designed in such way that third party won't interfere:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transport_Layer_Security
And considering that google requires all connections to them to be over ssl I really don't think you could change the conversation between their server and your computer.

Comment: I know about Wireshark and Charles. Viewing doesn't do anything for me, unfortunately. I wonder if, with admin privileges, I could inject a response into HTTPS. But let's say HTTP only and address at least that part of the question. There must be a way to do this, no?

Comment: I think [this post](http://serverfault.com/questions/318960/easy-way-to-edit-the-traffic-coming-from-a-tcp-host-linux) could help you. The principal explained there could be applied in your situation.